# redirect is not going to separate page

Tags: php, ajax

I have a sign in page that uses Ajax to send username and password to a php file to verify.  If the verification fails, it sends a message back to the user stating this on the sign in page under the create account button.  This is good.  If the user/password is correct, I want to redirect to the users account page.  This is working also, but it is ending up in the same place as the failed verification - on the sign in page under the create account button.  I understand why this is happen, I am not sure how to get the redirect to just show the new page on it's own page.  Thanks

See for yourself - [kyzereyephotography.com/examples/signIn/signIn.php](http://kyzereyephotography.com/examples/signIn/signIn.php)

username/pass - 123@123.com / 123

use an incorrect password to see the failed message

Here is the code:

signIn.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sign IN</title>
    <link href="../dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../dist/css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="../">Code Example - Log In</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> </br></br>

<!-- Sign In Form -->
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-signin" id="login_form" action="checkLogin.php" method="post">
        <p>
          This bit of code asks you to log in.  If you do not have an account, you can create one and then log on to it. 
        </p>
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input name="username" id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button id="signin" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" >Sign in</button>
      </form>
<!-- Create Accout Form -->
      <form class="form-signin">
         <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" value = "Create Account" onclick="window.location.href='createAccount.php'"/>
      </form>
        <span id="badpass"></span> <!--place to put the error message if password or username is bad-->
    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- JavaScript-->
  <!-- this script is used to validate the username and password.  JavaScript is used to pass data to checklogin.php-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#signin").click( function() {
      var data = $("#login_form :input").serializeArray();
      $.post( $("#login_form").attr("action"), data, function(info) { $("#badpass").html(info);});
      });
      $("#login_form").submit(function() {
        return false;
      });
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

checkLogin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
    include "includes/dbconnect.php";

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $userPassword = $_POST['password'];


    $query1 = "SELECT first_name, last_name, password FROM profiles WHERE email = '$username'";

    $results1 = mysql_query($query1,$dbconnect) or die ("Error in query1. ". mysql_error($dbconnect));      
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results1);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($results1);
    $hashedPass = $row['password'];

    if($count == 1)
    {
        if (crypt($userPassword, $hashedPass) == $hashedPass)
        {
            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

            header("location: profilesPage.php");
            die();

        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div style='color: red; font-size: 20px; text-align: center;'>ID or Password does not match</div>";
        }
        exit();

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div style='color: red; font-size: 20px; text-align: center;'>Bad username or password</div>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Please update your script to [MySQLi()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for security reasons! Mysql is deprecated!

Next my approach for your problem would be something like this:

```
$("#signin").click( function() {
    var data = $("#login_form :input").serializeArray();
    $.post(
        $("#login_form").attr("action"),
        data,
        function(info) {
            if(info == ""){ //Insert good password response here
                window.location.href = ""; //Url to profile page here
            } else {
                $("#badpass").html(info);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That works great for the redirect to the profile page, but now my failed verification redirects to another page.

Comment: @JeffKyzer It's a bit hard for me to see what exactly is going wrong like this. Pls click my name and contact me through email (include entire code in zip or rar if possible) so I can have a better look.